# iPhone sdk: how to delete duplicates in the NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

Hi  My NSArray contains duplicates like this(i have to delete the duplicates)

titles: Father's Day

titles: Father's Day

titles: Father's Day

titles: Election Day

titles: Election Day

titles: Election Day

titles: Easter

titles: Easter

titles: Earth Day

titles: Earth Day

titles: Earth Day

titles: Cinco de Mayo

titles: Cinco de Mayo

titles: Cinco de Mayo

titles: Christmas Eve

titles: Christmas Eve

titles: Christmas Eve

titles: Christmas
titles: Christmas
titles: Christmas

I have keep one name only and other duplicates are not wanted.
how i have do this please guide me with bit clear explanation, to solve this issue. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

If you care about ordering, you can create a new mutable array, loop through each object in the old array and only add it if it doesn't already exist:

```
NSMutableArray *uniqueItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id item in allItems)
    if (![uniqueItems containsObject:item])
        [uniqueItems addObject:item];
```

If not, it's much simpler to just use a set:

```
NSSet *uniqueItems = [NSSet setWithArray:allItems];
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a `NSSet` in the first place.

Comment: The runtime complexity of your "care about ordering" solution isn't very good. NSArray's containsObject has linear runtime complexity, i.e. it possibly has to do a comparison with every item in the array. A solution involving buckets, for example NSSet, gives you better performance.

Comment: Plus, his input array appears to be sorted (although the OP doesn't specify this explicitly) -- so you soln is a little complex in that case too.

Comment: There is also `NSOrderedSet`, available since iOS 5/OS X 10.7

Answer (score 2):

Is your NSArray that you wish to dedupe already sorted? It appears so from your question. In that case, the following code would do:

```
NSMutableArray *uniqueItems = [NSMutableArray array];

id lastSeenUniqueObject = nil;

for (NSObject *item in allItems) {
    if (![item isEqual:lastSeenUniqueObject]) {
        [uniqueItems addObject:item];
        lastSeenUniqueObject = item;
    }
}
```

This has a runtime complexity of N (i.e. fast), as compared to the (approx) N^2 complexity of rpetrich's answer.

If you *don't* know that the Array's contents is sorted, you have two options:

A) just sort it and then apply the above algorithm, which gives `n log n` runtime complexity (way better than N^2 still),

or

B) use an `NSMutableSet` to track already seen objects (or any other datastructure that uses buckets and hashing). The code would be like this:

```
NSMutableArray *uniqueItems = [NSMutableArray array];

NSMutableSet *seenItems = [NSMutableSet set];

for (NSObject *item in allItems) {
    if (![seenItems containsObject:item]) {
        [uniqueItems addObject:item];
        [seenItems addOBject:item];
    }
}
```

This also gives a runtime better than N^2.

Answer (score 0):

See simple this..

```
NSMutableArray *dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"December 29,2010", 
                             @"December 28,2010",
                             @"December 22,2010",
                             @"December 22,2010",
                             @"December 22,2010",@"December 21,2010",@"December 28,2010",nil];
```

for Avoid Duplicate use this...

```
NSSet *cleanedArray = [NSSet setWithArray:dateArray];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[cleanedArray allObjects]];

for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"The Given Array is %@",[array objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Comment: A NSSet is not magically turned into a NSArray when you assign it. It's still a NSSet, and all NSArray methods you use on it will lead to a crash.

Comment: have you tried? Add `NSLog(@"First Object: %@", [cleanedArray objectAtIndex:0]);` to your code.

Comment: k i agreed ur point.... this is simple method to get. but before asking he should specify tat should not use NSSET.......

Comment: It has nothing to do with his question or with NSSet. It's just wrong when YOU write `NSArray *foo = [NSSet ...`

Comment: Now This would be correct.. it's still a NSArray not nsset... Mr. Fluch

Comment: -1 because your soln loses the ordering information in the original NSArray.

Comment: NOTE: although you may put data in an NSSet on an occaison and pull it out in the same order, it's isn't guaranteed behaviour. So you can't rely on it always happening in the future.

Comment: If you wanna sort, then should use NSSortDescriptor.  Dont You know this silly Info... mr Occulus.......,  mind it the questionare doesnot specify to order .... but U damn ....

Comment: What's NSSortDescriptor got to do with it? You posted a solution which is broken -- in a way that might not even be obvious initially. It's not a good answer, because unless otherwise specified, one should maintain all the information in the input data, which includes ordering in the case of arrays.

Comment: so now Wat you Wanna do?.////.  i will make it as good answer.. could you tell now....,

Comment: Sorry, you're not communicating very clearly, and I'm finding you hard to understand. I recommend reading the "Spelling, grammar and formatting" section at this link: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: sorry..... thanks for letting me know the mistakes.. i will be very happy if you tell what you r coming to say.... or else u just come to objective c room...