# How to remove duplicate values from array

Tags: arrays, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have one NSMutableArray which containing duplicates value e.g.[1,2,3,1,1,6]. I want to remove duplicates value and want new array with distinct values.

Comment: This SO question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025674/the-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [The best way to remove duplicate values from NSMutableArray in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025674/the-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c)

Comment: see this too. i was answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281295/iphone-sdk-how-to-delete-duplicates-in-the-nsarray/5281491#5281491

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The best way to remove duplicate values from NSMutableArray in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025674/the-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 18):

two liner

```
NSMutableArray *uniqueArray = [NSMutableArray array];

[uniqueArray addObjectsFromArray:[[NSSet setWithArray:duplicateArray] allObjects]];
```

Comment: And use `NSOrderedSet` if you want the original order.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

```
array1=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"2",@"3",@"3",@"3",@"2",@"5",@"6",@"6",nil];
array2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (id obj in array1) 
{
    if (![array2 containsObject:obj]) 
    {
        [array2 addObject: obj];
    }
}
NSLog(@"new array is %@",array2);
```

The output is: 1,2,3,5,6..... Hope it's help you. :)

Comment: hi can you tell me can i count no of duplicate element in array1 like 2 is coming in thrice time.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a category on NSArray with this method in :

```
- (NSArray *)arrayWithUniqueObjects {
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self count]];

    for (id item in self)
        if (NO == [newArray containsObject:item])
            [newArray addObject:item];

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:newArray];
}
```

However, this is brute force and not very efficient, there's probably a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the values is not important, the easiest way is to create a set from the array:

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:myArray];
```

It will only contain unique objects:

> If the same object appears more than once in array, it is added only once to the returned set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the order, check this solution

```
// iOS 5.0 and later
NSArray * newArray = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:oldArray] array];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSSet approach is the best if you're not worried about the order of the objects

```
 uniquearray = [[NSSet setWithArray:yourarray] allObjects];
```